# Category archive in with conjunction with custom post type is empty

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, terms

I've set up a custom post type that works as intended:

```
add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\work_post_type' );
function work_post_type() {
    // set up labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Work',
        'singular_name' => 'Work',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Work',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Work',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Work',
        'new_item' => 'New Work',
        'all_items' => 'All Work',
        'view_item' => 'View Work',
        'search_items' => 'Search Work',
        'not_found' =>  'No Work Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Work found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Work',
    );
    //register post type
    register_post_type( 'work', array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'client', 'category' ),    
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'work' ),
        )
    );
}
```

As you can see I've included `category` as a taxonomy for this custom post type.
I've added two categories that are in use on the site. But if I go to the archive of any of the categories I've added, it returns no posts, although there are posts associated. Is it because it's a custom post type and the query doesn't pick up on it?

[image]

What I find weird is that my custom created taxonomy `client` works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress only includes the `post` post type for Category archives by default, but you can add additional post types by altering the query:

```
function wpse241719_add_custom_types_to_category_archives( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array(
                         'post',
                         'work',
                         // 'another_post_type',
                    ) );
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse241719_add_custom_types_to_category_archives' );
```

Comment: Haha! Just as I posted the question I found a similar snippet. Was just about to answer myself. Thanks!

Comment: :-) Shout out to CSS tricks. That's where I plundered this solution from.